# How to display text in a TextBox on a Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

There are several answers online about this question but none of them have answered my question. I have a Windows Form which has a list of details of a user, some of the data can be edited while some cannot. I want to 'getUserName()' (Which returns a username) and display it in a Textbox

```
    // Display Student Details Form
    public void displayStudent()
    {
        StudentDetails sd = new StudentDetails();
        sd.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The above creates the new form which contains several labels and textboxes, when it is created (and displayed), the textboxes on that form should populate to contain student information (such as username, name, address etc)

```
    private void displayUserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        displayUserName.Text = displayUserName.Text = s.getUserName();
    }
```

s is a Student Object

The above code, I wish to take the username from the student object and display it in a textbox for another user to see and possibly edit.

Comment: Are you wanting the `"Hello"` added after the text has changed in the box? That would appear to be what your code is showing here.

Comment: So I have an empty textbox displaying nothing, I want to add data to the textbox for a user to view and then possibly edit.

Comment: The adding data to the textbox is supposed to be triggered by what? That is the part you haven't mentioned as you could put it into the form's initialization, user clicks a button or any of 101 other triggers beyond the user modifying the text in the box.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully help.

Comment: Does your constructor fill in that data by default without any parameters? If not, where is the data coming for that `sd` instance to have the data?

Comment: `displayUserName.Text = displayUserName.Text = s.getUserName();` would appear to be a typo or you really want some weird stuff as using the assignment operator in that fashion makes for confusing code if nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code where note that I do specify that the Text for the `displayUserName` box is given after I've created the object and the `x` is merely whatever you have for ensuring that the instance has the data set to use rather than being blank that would continue the bug.

```
// Display Student Details Form
public void displayStudent()
{
    StudentDetails sd = new StudentDetails();
    sd.getData(x);
    displayUserName.Text = sd.getUserName();
    sd.ShowDialog();
}
```

The `TextChanged` call would be what you'd use after the user has changed the value of the text box and is something to do as part of a processing the form rather than initializing it, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Just try `displayUserName.Text = s.getUserName();`

Put this in the Form Load event, on a Button press or comboBox Selection event... Making some assumptions (Because you did not provide many details), for instance in your StudentDetails Form code behind:

```
public partial class StudentDetails : Form
{
    private int _studentId;

    private DbContext _context;

    public StudentDetails(int studentId)
    {
        _context = new DbContext();
        _studentId = studentId;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        Student s = _context.Students.Find(_studentId);

        displayUserName.Text = s.getUserName();
        // Using a function here is overkill, perhaps.
        // This should also work here:
        // displayUserName.Text = s.FullName;


        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

Now in your main form:

```
StudentDetails form = new StudentDetails(studentId);
form.ShowDialog() ;
```

As an aside, most people will not bother answering your question if you do not at least try and then show what you have tried.